# Is the "low number estimate-to-high number estimate" colloquialism/phraseology unknown in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, coloquialismos

In "The Grapes of Wrath," the estimate "fifty-sixty" is translated into Spanish (in "Las Uvas de la Ira") as "cincuenta y seis" (56).

Apparently the translator thought "fifty-sixty" was a typo (that what was meant was "fifty-six"). Is the rough estimate expressed thus in English unknown in Spanish? Is that why the translator made that assumption?

e.g., when English (American English?) speakers say something like this, it could be in the form: "I see fifty-sixty cars go by here every day." and what they mean by that is, "I see fifty to sixty cars go by here every day."

Comment: The translator was victim of the lack of context...remember translator like google, bing, etc could be great for just one word, but very wrong with expression...in Spanish we use in the same way as your example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will be translated as "cincuenta a sesenta".

The speaker can use the preposition ("a") to express the range of a quantity.

A dash ("Guión Ortográfico") between two words is used to create a compound word.
Example: físico-química = physicochemical

Traduction of your Example:

- I see fifty-sixty cars go by here everyday => Veo cincuenta a sesenta carros que pasan por aquí todos los días.